# Python Error - no viable alternative input when trying to insert values from file

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to insert some values from a csv file through Python but I'm getting a `no viable alternative at input` error. When I specify the values instead of `%s` the code works but when I try to use `%s` it fails. This is my code:

```
import jaydebeapi
import jpype
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import csv

conn = pyodbc.connect("myconnection")
cursor = conn.cursor()
with open('/Users/user/Desktop/TEST.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (user_id, email) VALUES(%s,%s)", row)

#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: You should use `?` instead of `%s` in the query string

Comment: thank you!! it works, I appreciate it :)